# Login alerts for wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress, security

is there any way to implement a login alert in a WordPress website  whereby whenever a user login from a different region, the latter is notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is. Look at this action hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

And this is your pseudo-code:

```
function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {

// get previous regions the user logged in

// check current region

// notify if abnormal behaviour

}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
```

Have fun with the exact implementation :-)

Edit: Also nice to know the wp_authenticate action hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate

This one you use if you want to do something with login attempts before the actual login happens.

Comment: how can i retrieve the regions of users once they logged in? is it through their ip address?

Comment: infact there is a two factor authentication where users need to approve from their mobile. in order for the users to not be irritated with approving each time, they get the opportunity save from browser , is it possible to do so in wordpress?

Comment: Yes it is and my answer is all you need to start. Just use the wp_authenticate and the wp_login hook appropriatly. If you want to avoid that they are asked each time just set a cookie in their browser.